# Find the lowest $t$ to make the graph connected

Tags: algorithms, computer-science

> Let a directed and connected graph, $G=(V,E)$, with positive weights. for every $t>0$ we define $E(t)$ to be the set of edges where their weights are at most $t$. Describe an algorithm to calculate the minimal $t$ such that $G(t)=(V,E(t))$ is connected.

I really don't understand why isn't finding an MST (using Prim/Kruskal) the solution for this? What is the correct solution?

Thanks

Comment: How exactly do you want to use your MST in finding the value of $t$? How do you use a MST to detect when the graph is or isn't connected?

Comment: I wonder if some type of greedy algorithm will works. Just start removing edges of maximum weight such that the graph does not becomes disconnected. If it does becomes disconnected, remove the next largest weight and so on. If we cannot remove any more edges this way then we have found the desired graph.Then we will find the maximum of all weight of edges of this desired graph. But I don't know whether this type of algorithm will always give a/the solution.

Comment: @AsharTafhim, the algorithm needs to be efficient.

Comment: @MikePierce, MST is a connected sub-graph of $G$ with minimal edges. Why isn't it the solution?

Comment: MSTs are not unique. Given an MST, how do you know the minimal $t$ associated with that one is *the* minimal $t$. You would have to look at every possible MST, find the corresponding $t$ for each one, and take the smallest one among those as your solution. But that's not efficient.

Comment: I think that finding an MST using Prim or Kruskal will give you a correct solution to your problem only on undirected graphs. Just remember the edge $e$ with largest weight contained in the MST $W$. If you remove this edge from the tree you get a cut $(S,T)$. Let $t^*$ be the minimal $t$ such that $G(t)$ is connected. Since $G(t^*)$ is connected, it must contain at least one edge crossing the cut $(S,T)$. But $e$ is the edge crossing this cut with minimal weight (otherwise, $W$ would not be a MST). Thus, $t^* \geq t(e)$.

Comment: MSTs are (as far as I know) only defined on undirected graph. However, your problem is defined on directed graphs. Also, note that on directed graphs, connected means that there must exist a directed path from $u$ to $v$ or from $v$ to $u$ for each pair of nodes $(u, v)$.